# Can I Take off from top and side of a trunk line under same bay?

Tags: hvac, ducts

Could you please help me.

There is an article about 2 foot rule of take off.
https://hvactoday.com/0719-two-foot-rule/

In my case, There is already an existing take off from the top , can i directly have another take off from the side of trunk in same bay ? I don't have other option.

The below picture is source from above site and I edited the picture to show my requirement ?

I can move the new take off to one bay left and right . but it doesn't fall under 2 foot rule. so I am not sure if directly across and my requirement are similar.

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be fine, because the issue with the spacing has to do with static air pressure and flow right *after* a reduction in cross-section or right *after* a tap-off. I don't think the relative orientation of the tap-offs matters (opposing 180deg vs. 90 deg).

Comment: Agree with P2000. This should be Ok.  There might be less air flow as flow is distributed but there would be very minimal turbulence. but if the take off was taken from next side,  there would be some turbulence which could reduce the static pressure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the trunk on top of the location in the trunk. If you have 2 large taps two close to each other they will drastically affect each other, also when changing size or terminating a run it is best to not to tap at the change. If a large trunk and both taps go to the same room it is not as big a deal.  separate rooms opening 1 room for higher flow can cut the flow in the other room by 50% and that makes balancing each room really tough, it can be done but one room may not have the proper air flow for the pipe size because of the 2 taps close together.
Before building a few Homes and experiencing this I did not think it would matter because pressure is pressure right? Well air flow at sub sonic flow rates can create low pressure zones and about 18” separation is needed so I think that’s why they came up with the 24” rule.

Comment: In short, what you are saying.. Not OK ?